# make cursor just focuses on textbox in c#

Tags: c#, rfid

I have a textbox in my c# application that gets the code from `RFID Reader` The RFID reader is connected to my computer using `USB port` .So My textbox should always be aware to read the data from RFIDReader because i can't lose the data .

The RFID Reader is plug and play .and it works like a keyboard and reads the data from the RFID card and returns the serial .

My solution is just create a textbox to get the received data .But how can i sure that every time the cursor is focused on my textbox to get the data .Do you have better solution if No My question is :

```
how can i sure that every time the cursor is focused on my textbox to get the data?
```

maybe the better solution is get the data from the socket ?!

Comment: If you can count of your form having the focus always, you can use the KeyPreview property to redirect input to your TextBox.

Comment: @CecilioPardo what you mean by If you can count of your form having the focus always

Comment: If the user switches to another application, then you can't get keyboard input in a "normal" way.

Comment: @CecilioPardo yes the user maybe opens another application

Comment: @CecilioPardo can i read the data from socket?

Comment: If the device works as a keyboard, probably not. But you need to check its docs. Maybe it can work some other way, maybe not. Anyway, if it needs to work like a keyboard, it will be difficult to allow app switching and still get the input right.

Comment: @CecilioPardo if i force my users to don't switch to another programs can i use keypreview?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said on my first comment. Investigate KeyPreview and you'll probably get what you need.

Comment: Usually RFID readers will provide a non-keyboard driver (HID or Serial, in my experience).  Post the model of the RFID reader for better guidance. If you really can't use anything but a keyboard driver, you could use `RawInput` with `RI_NOLEGACY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your textbox always the focused control, set the focus back when it's lost:

```
textBox1.Leave += (o, e) => { textBox1.Focus(); };
```

You should write this code into the constructor after InitializeComponent.